# how do i search a struct of arrays for a particular character without using pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

i created a struct which has as one of its fields, a 2d array to store seats booked..in the main section, i have created an array of structs so as to store all the information.when i enter a row and column number, the program have to check if that seat has been booked already..the problem i have is that my program is not checking properly for this case..i have tried checking the entire array but i do not know how to properly do that..please assist me as i am still a newbie..

I have tried checking the entire array as you will see in my code..i have commented that part out, because i also tried only checking by only one instance of the array of structures

`````````````````````````````````````````````````
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Simulate
{


        string seats[3][3] = {};
        string name = "";
        int age = 0;
        int rowNum, colNum;

};

``````````````````````````````````````````
void getinput(Simulate &book)
{


        cout<<"Enter your name: "<<endl;
        cin>>book.name;
        cout<<"Enter your age: "<<endl;
        cin>>book.age;
        cout<<"enter row number: "<<endl;
        cin>>book.rowNum;
        cout<<"enter column number: "<<endl;
        cin>>book.colNum;


}



void setSeats(Simulate &book)
{


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            book.seats[i][j] = "o";

        }

    }
}

void bookMap(Simulate &book)

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
          //cout<<i<<endl;
          cout<<endl<<"\t";
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
          {

            cout<<book.seats[i][j]<<"  ";

          }
          cout<<endl;

        }

    }



void bookMapUpdated(Simulate &book)

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

          cout<<endl<<"\t";
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
          {

            cout<<book.seats[i][j]<<"  ";

          }
          cout<<endl;

        }

    }

/*
bool checkBooking(Simulate book[])

    {
                //assuming only 2 structs created
           for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
           {

             if (book[i].seats[book[i].rowNum][book[i].colNum] == "o")
             {
                return true;
             }
             else
             {
                return false;
             }
    }
     */

bool checkBooking(Simulate book)

    {


             if (book.seats[book.rowNum][book.colNum] == "o")
             {
                return true;
             }
             else
             {
                return false;
            }
    }

```````````````````````````````````````````````` 
int main()

    {
      Simulate bookings[2];
      int i = 0;
      char answer;

      getinput(bookings[i]);
      setSeats(bookings[i]);
      bookMap(bookings[i]);

       if (checkBooking(bookings[i]) == true )
       {
         bookings[i].seats[bookings[i].rowNum][bookings[i].colNum] = "x";
       }
       else
       {
           cout<<"seat  booked please choose another seat"<<endl;
           cin>>bookings[i].rowNum>>bookings[i].colNum;
       }

       cout<<"do you want to make another booking y/n"<<endl;
       cin>>answer;

       while (answer == 'y' || answer =='Y')
       {
           i++;
           getinput(bookings[i]);
           bookMapUpdated(bookings[i]);

           if (checkBooking(bookings[i]) == true )
           {
             bookings[i].seats[bookings[i].rowNum][bookings[i].colNum] = "x";
           }
           else
           {
           cout<<"seat  booked please choose another seat"<<endl;
           cin>>bookings[i].rowNum;
           cin>>bookings[i].colNum;
           }

        cout<<"do you want to make another booking y/n"<<endl;
        cin>>answer;

       }

       system("pause");
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
`````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correctly looking for a character in a 2D array and using pointers would not help.

The problem is that you are using a different `seats` structure for every booking. To solve your problem, make the `seats` array unique and work with this one on every booking.

Apart from that, there is some problems with your code. First, you are using an array of two bookings, but you allow the user to input as many bookings as he wants. This will create memory corruption after 2 bookings. Second, when the seat is taken, you ask for another seat but you do not check if the new one is taken.

Comment: hey thanks for your assistance... your suggestions makes sense..i am thinking hard now about making the seats array unique ..am i correct in saying that the seats array is unique to the Simulate struct but not unique to the array of structs?

Comment: Yes, but I would formulate it differently: There is a single "seats" array in an instance of "Simulate", so there are many "seats" arrays in the whole program. What you can do is to take the "seats" array out of the "Simulate" structure and create only one instance of it. I would also rename the "Simulate" structure since the name does not clearly tells what is the role of the class in the whole program. Maybe a "Threater" class that contains the seats, and a "Booking" class that contains information for one booking?

Comment: hey thanks even as a global variable i am getting the seats booked correctly..you a star..